Refine identification on this "tactile" switch
I'd like to identify this switch:

After poking around on Digikey and comparing the measurements, I believe it's a Panasonic EVQ-P0N02B or EVQ-P0Q02Q. It does not have a GND terminal. The button width dictates it's an Overstroke type switch, not Short travel, meaning it can only be 0.6N or 1.0N. Those factors plus the measurements seem to narrow it down to those two PNs. Datasheet here covers both models.
Now I'm just wondering if there are any other switch series from other manufacturers that it could be from.
I'm also wondering if the numbers on it tell me anything. From top left to bottom right, they read "1 4 9 2" (the switch is shown rotated about 135 degrees in the photo). The Panasonic datasheet doesn't say anything about part markings.
Rotated view for easier reading:

For comparison, I ordered some of the two PNs I suspect from Panasonic, and their markings don't clearly match to the PNs:
Panasonic EVQ-P0N02B has markings 3 6 C 3
Panasonic EVQ-P0Q02Q has markings 2 6 D 3

Very good photo and measurements! +1

I bet the marking are 1 4 8 2 and not "1 4 9 2"

@Andyaka I'm confident that's a 9 not an 8. I've added a rotated and cropped image that makes that clear. Thanks.

The numbers may be a date code, manufacturing location or something else entirely like a code for model. They're not specified on the datasheet, as far as I can see. You also have an operating force specification, of which there are quite a few choices.
If you're looking for alternative manufacturers of a compatible switch, check out Alps, for example SKRAAQE010.

Thanks for the Alps link. Those certainly look like they'd be an alternate source for some of the Panasonic ones in the datasheet I linked. I'll have a look through the rest of their offerings and see if there's a match for my measurements. (the datasheet you linked appears to only cover 3.4mm tall switches which is much taller than what I'm looking at).

PS: I've added details about force spec in my question. In brief, at least for the Panasonic series, the button width dictates it's an "Overstroke" type switch, meaning it only comes in 0.6N or 1.0N. Which is how I arrived at the two candidate PNs.

PPS: A bonus to the Alps switches is their lower force ones, like 0.6N, are rated for 4M cycles, compared to 2M for Panasonic.

It's also possible you've got a clone of the Panasonic switch, but hints from the photo suggest to me that's unlikely.
